# Scala Unit to Anonymous Class

Tags: scala, closures, anonymous-class

Is it possible to convert a Unit to a method of an anonymous class?

Instead of:

```
addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener{
    def widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event): Unit = {
       //...
    }
}
```

To this:

```
addSelectionListener toAnonymousClass(classOf[SelectionListener], { 
    /* .. */ 
})
```

If there aren't any libraries that can do this, how would I go about making one? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following implicit conversion should achieve the result you want:

```
implicit def selectionListener (f: SelectionEvent => Unit) = 
  new SelectionListener {
    def widgetSelected(event: SelectionEvent) {
      f(event)
    }
  }
```

It'll automatically convert your function literals of type `SelectionEvent => Unit` into the `SelectionListener` so you'll be able to use the `addSelectionListener` method like so:

```
addSelectionListener { event: SelectionEvent =>
    /* .. */ 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write something that'd work on any interface with 
a single method and single parameter?

Comment: Nope, it's not. 1. The current return type of `selectionListener` implicit is `SelectionListener` - what would you expect it to be if the function was able to return other types? 2. Even if all the types you expected this function to return did implement some higher interface like, say, `Listener` and you made it the return type of conversion, how would you resolve which implementation to return inside the conversion? So basically you should just create an implicit for each Anonymous class you want to use by the provided example.

Comment: Makes sense :). You reuse a lot of the same listeners anyway, so it's still far less boilerplate than writing all the anonymous classes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an overload to `addSelectionListener`, so that you don't need an implicit conversion. From 2.10, such conversions require an import of `language.implicitConversions` which is a subtle hint that you should avoid them if possible.

```
def addSelectionListener(f: SelectionEvent => Unit) = 
  addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener {
    def widgetSelected(event: SelectionEvent): Unit = f(event)
  }
})
```

Then use as

```
addSelectionListener { se => 
  /* ... */
}
```

which is also less boilerplate because you don't need the type annotation.

If you use it in other places you could put the overload method in a subclass of whatever `addSelectionListener` is defined in, or in a trait.